# sqlite NULL_DISTINCT_FOR_UNIQUE setting for distinct NULL values in Unqiue Table constraint

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to set the NULL_DISTINCT_FOR_UNIQUE to 1 for UNIQUE constraints to handle null as a distinct value? I found a really old link that shows this, but I cant figure out how to set it. I dont see it in the sqlite3.h header file anywhere:

http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/sqlite_api.html

Id like for my table to handle NULL as a unique for a table level constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol NULL_DISTINCT_FOR_UNIQUE doesn't seem to be defined in the current version of the source code. I suppose it could have been renamed or moved from sqlite.h to a different file.

Looks like it [might have been removed](http://www.sqlite.org/sqllogictest/ci/10318b880cb756b267cb9ffa4a301fb97bb17307) in 3.6.23.

You can [download the source](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and look through sqlite3.h for something similar.

Comment: it was removed here: http://www.sqlite.org/sqllogictest/ci/10318b880cb756b267cb9ffa4a301fb97bb17307

Comment: I think that's the same link I posted above.